# How I can handle PointerMoved events in Scrollviewer

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, windows-runtime

I have grid inside ScrollViewer, and grid subscribed on Holding event and PointerMoved event. But when holding event raised, fires PointerCaptureCancelled event and PointerMoved events not fireds. I tried disable scrollviewer, but actually it doesnt works. Also I read [Where did my gestures go](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/blogs/wsdevsol/where-did-all-my-gestures-go), but it doesnt works now. How should I handle Pointer events inside ScrollViewer?

Comment: Could you please tell me if you want to fire the PointerMoved event when Holding event is fired? In my side, the PointerMoved event and Holding event are all fired when I have a Grid inside a ScrollViewer. Could you please provide us with detailed code about your Grid and ScrollViewer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CancelDirectManipulstions in the handle event.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.canceldirectmanipulations?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_CancelDirectManipulations